# How to Solve Failed to Read Object Schema Error while Running React-native app connecting realm

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I am new to React-native,Please suggest how can I solve this problem
Thanks in Advance.
Versions used :
"react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.71.8","realm": "^11.9.0"

Following error is getting while runing react-native app using realm.   [Attaching error of terminal][1]

Error: Exception in HostFunction: Failed to read ObjectSchema: properties must be of type 'object', got (undefined), js engine: hermes

Following is my Realm Schema  Contact(Contact.js)

```
import Realm from "realm";
class Contact extends Realm.Object { }

Contact.schema = {

    name: "Contact",
    Properties: {
        givenName: 'String',
        familyName: 'String',
        phoneNumber: 'String'
    },
    primaryKey: "recordId",
}
 let realm = new Realm({ schema: [Contact], SchemaVersion: 4 })

let getAllContacts = () => {
    return realm.Object("Contact");
}
 let addContact = (_recordID, _givenName, _familyName, _phoneNumber) => {
    realm.write(() => {
        const Contact = realm.create("Contact", {
            recordID: _recordID,
            givenName: _givenName,
            familyName: _familyName,
            phoneNumber: _phoneNumber
        });
    })
}
 let deleteContact = realm.write(() => {
    realm.delete(getAllContacts)
})

export { getAllContacts, addContact, deleteContact }`
export default realm;
```